# how install ubuntu touch on x86 tablet through the BIOS?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, tablet

Entered on this link http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/ When the pressure on the 32-bit PC (i386) preinstalled touch image I found the file extension tar.gz 
So how install the system through the BIOS

Comment: You need to create a bootable drive with the ubuntu touch image. What OS will you be creating the drive on?

Comment: tablet dual os windows and android

Comment: Your question does have enough details and those not explicitly  mention the items in your __title__.